# Get all the logs as HTTP response in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend

I am trying to build a utility method wherein passing a query param like "debug=true" with any HTTP API of my service will give me all the log statements printed by the application as HTTP response.

My application is running on Spring Boot. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

I have used logging level in application.properties to print all HTTP requests/responses, method url in the log file

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
logging.file=E:/log/app.log
```

I have used Spring Boot.